# How to add actions to the system menu/window menu of open windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to add a new entry to the system menu/window menu of all open windows that performs a certain action when clicked. I used `GetSystemMenu` and `InsertMenuItem` to add my entry the system menu. This is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsCallback(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam)
{
    HMENU systemMenu = GetSystemMenu(hWnd, FALSE);

    MENUITEMINFO alwaysOnTop;
    alwaysOnTop.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
    alwaysOnTop.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_STRING;
    alwaysOnTop.fType = MFT_RADIOCHECK | MFT_STRING;
    alwaysOnTop.dwTypeData = (wchar_t*)L"Always on top";
    alwaysOnTop.cch = 20;

    MENUITEMINFO separator;
    separator.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
    separator.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE;
    separator.fType = MFT_SEPARATOR;

    InsertMenuItem(systemMenu, 0, TRUE, &alwaysOnTop);
    InsertMenuItem(systemMenu, 1, TRUE, &separator);

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    EnumWindows(enumWindowsCallback, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

However, I don't know who it's possible to perform an action when the user clicks on my new entry in the system window?

My goal is to add a button that sets the window always on top and reverse.

Comment: Even if you could somehow get this working, when your menu items are clicked on, they will send `WM_(SYS)COMMAND` messages to the window that owns the menu, so if you want to handle those messages yourself then you will have to hook the message processing of every window, such as with `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC)`. Which means you are also going to have to assign unique IDs to your menu items, which you are not currently doing, as that is the only value `WM_(SYS)COMMAND` will give you back to identify which item was clicked.

Comment: I can easily assign ids to my menu items. Is it possible to hook the message processing of every window? Can I use `SetWindowsHookEx` for each window and check for the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message? That's the message that is sent according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmenu#remarks.

Comment: "*Is it possible to hook the message processing of every window?*" - yes. "*Can I use `SetWindowsHookEx`*" - yes.